# is the Compare-And-Set operation with Memcache equal to transactions with ndb?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just have one simple question:

let's think of a counter, which many task might want to access at the same time.

Do transactions with ndb (with active memcache and cache) avoid the same kind of collisions I avoid with a counter directly in Memcache, using the Compare-And-Set operation?

What is basically a 'collision' for transaction with ndb?

Comment: Did you find out any information about this? Thanks.